# What am I misunderstanding about the d3 enter() and exit () selections?

Tags: d3.js

I'm learning D3. In this example, I'm adding paragraphs, using a simple list of numbers as data. I try to do the following things:

1. Start with a list of 5 elements. When I call update(), I think the enter selection should contain 5 paragraphs and the exit() selection should be empty.
2. Add one number to the data. The enter selection should contain this single paragraph and the exit selection should be empty.
3. Remove all the numbers except for two. Here the exit selection should contain 4 paragraphs and the enter selection should be empty.

However, this is not what I see! I make the update function print the amount of elements, like this:

```
console.log('paras: '+paras[0].length+ ' enter: '+parasE[0].length + ' exit: '+paras.exit()[0].length);
```

And, for the three times it is called, I get this output:

```
"paras: 5 enter: 5 exit: 5" 
"paras: 6 enter: 6 exit: 6"
"paras: 6 enter: 6 exit: 6"
```

As I understand it, as I'm using indexing to do the data join (and not a key), either the exit selection or the enter selection are always empty. Am I misunderstanding this, or am I using the wrong method to check how many elements are in the selections?

It seems that all elements are being removed and re-added each time (which is why the enter and exit selections are both full). What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks,
Louise

Full example code (will run from a local HTML file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>D3 Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.4.5"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

d3.select("body").append("span")
    .text("Hello, world!");

    data1=[1,2,3,4,5];

    function update(){
      paras=d3.select('body').selectAll('p').data(data1);

      parasE=paras.enter();

      console.log('paras: '+paras[0].length+ ' enter: '+parasE[0].length + ' exit: '+paras.exit()[0].length);

      paras.enter().append('p').html(function(d){return d});

      paras.exit().remove();  
    }

    update();
    data1.push(10);
    update();
    data1=[1,2];
    update(); 

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that D3 selections aren't quite arrays and shouldn't be treated as such. In particular (from [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections)):

> One nuance is that selections are grouped: rather than a one-dimensional array, each selection is an array of arrays of elements.

You're simply getting the size of the wrong selection arrays. Use [`.size()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#size) to get the size of a selection:

```
console.log('paras: '+paras.size()+ ' enter: '+parasE.size() + ' exit: '+paras.exit().size());
```

Complete example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gzpfnjfq/).

Comment: Thanks! I did understand after all :) I did try and use size but I was using an old version of d3 in which it didn't exist yet.